# Parent window domain prepended to Iframe src page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm inserting an iframe using javascript in the following way:

```
var s ="<p><iframe name=&quot;searchf&quot; src=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; height=&quot;350&quot;></iframe></p>";

var para = document.createElement("div");
para.innerHTML = s;

var element =  document.getElementById("some_div_id");
var child = document.getElementById("some_fieldset_id");
element.insertBefore(para,child);
```

Let's say the parent window domain is `http://www.parentwindowdomain.com/example1`. The problem is that the iframe src page is somehow interpreted in such a way that the parent window domain name is prepended to the specified src domain. For example, the resulting iframe src page address would turn out to erroneously be `http://www.parentwindowdomain.com/example1/"http://www.google.com"`

Is there a way to override this so that, in this case, the iframe src page would be `http://www.google.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this one, i think it is tidier.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpkp5sb2/

```
var s = document.createElement("iframe");
s.setAttribute("name", "searchf");
s.setAttribute("src", "http://www.example.com");
s.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
s.setAttribute("width", "100%");
s.setAttribute("height", "350");
var pp = document.createElement("p");
pp.appendChild(s);

var para = document.createElement("div");
para.appendChild(pp);

var element =  document.getElementById("some_div_id");
var child = document.getElementById("some_fieldset_id");
element.insertBefore(para,child);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by just removing all of the `&quot;` I had. But I like your solution! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You can also use '(single quote) instead of &quot;.